# Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail Image are not displaying properly in Magento

Tags: image, magento, program-entry-point, radix

I my thumbnails are not showing properly for multiple image view. On the admin side I can see all the different image set for a single product. I selected the default main, base and thumbnail image but on the front end I only see the default image. The other images dont show instead the default image is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I have found the problem. An extension was causing the conflict. I just simply unistalled the extension and everything started working Ok.
The culprit extension is called, 'Image Permalink' or 'IG_NamedImages' in the magento connect.

Please let me know if anyone was having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this module editing the IG_NamedImages_Model_Product_Image as the following:

```
class IG_NamedImages_Model_Product_Image extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
{
    public function setBaseFile($file)
    {
        parent::setBaseFile($file);

        if (Mage::helper('ig_namedimages')->getIsEnabled()){
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $imageName = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_url')->formatUrlKey($product->getName());
            $this->_newFile = preg_replace('/\/([^\/]+\.\w+)$/', '/'.$imageName.'-\1', $this->_newFile);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```